# Convert IF-statements in Switch-statement

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, expression, control-flow

I have a series of IF-statements and i would like to convert in a Switch-statement but I can't succeed in inserting an evaluation in case constant1 field of switch.

I know that Switch works that way:

```
switch ( expression ) {   //in my case:      switch (score) {
  case constant1:
    statement
      break;
  case constant2:
    statement
  default:
    statement
      break;
```

Now I've tried to put `<= 60` in the constant1 field, but of course it doesn't work.

This is the series of IF statements I want to convert in Switch.

```
if (score <= 60) {
    printf("F");
}
if (score <= 70 && score > 60) {
    printf("D");
}
if (score <= 80 && score > 70) {
    printf("C");
}
if (score <= 90 && score > 80) {
    printf("B");
}
if (score <= 100 && score > 90) {
    printf("A");
}
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Well, you can't really do that (in a sensible manner), but you could simplify your `if` chain by using `else if`s (and removing the `&&` conditions)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972297/larger-than-and-less-than-in-switch-statement-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`switch` statement takes constants, not conditions. For instance, you cannot say `>= const`, so you need to change the strategy.

For example, in your case you can switch on the first digit of your two-digit score, after subtracting `1` from it:

```
switch ((score-1) / 10) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5: printf("F"); break;
    case 6: printf("D"); break;
    case 7: printf("C"); break;
    case 8: printf("B"); break;
    case 9: printf("A"); break;
}
```

Cases 0..4 use C's fall-through mechanism for switch statements, all printing `"D"`.

The code above assumes that you have checked the range of the score to be 1..100, inclusive.

Comment: While not too clean, it's kinda smart and inventive and I like it. However, I don't think one should write code like this outside of educational programs. It's just gonna cause confusion.

Comment: @neoaggelos Absolutely! It is clear that the intention of this question is to learn a different technique as part of a learning process: all questions that I've seen on converting numeric grades to American letter grades were inevitably from students learning the language. Outside of educational setting writing clever code is often a bad idea: a chain of if-then-elses is much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, you can't do it like this since in `switch` statement, you can have only `1` expression.

Use if-else statement like this:

```
if (score <= 60) {
    printf("F");
} else if (score <= 70) {
    printf("D");
} else if (score <= 80) {
    printf("C");
}
//More statements
```

With enabled GCC extensions for switch, you can use like this:

```
switch (score) {
    case 0...60:
        break;
    case 61...70:
        break;
    //..More cases with range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` only checks for equality. Therefore in your case the if-else construct is way better suited.

Still, if you want to use a switch statement you have to do it like this:

```
switch (score) 
{
  case 0:
  case 1:
  case 2:
  ... // all cases up to 58
  case 59:
  case 60:
    printf("F");
    break;
  case 61:
  ...
}
```

Not really pretty and very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `case *constant*`, so you can't ever write a `case < 60`.

What you can do, is put several case commands below one another like this:

```
case 40:
case 41:
case 42:
case 43:
    // do stuff
break;
```

This will 'do stuff' if the switch statement is equal to 40, 41, 42 or 43. However, may I suggest that unless you have a good reason to convert your if-statements to switch-statements, you shouldn't in this particular occasion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` or `switch`, or you can simply:

```
 printf("%c", 70 - ((score - 60) > 0 ? (score - 41) / 10 : 0));
```

[Live example on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/09Hh8J)

P.S. Of course, similar can be used in `switch` statement to have exactly five `case`'s.

Answer (score 0):

A little digression.
You could try following pseudo. It is short and simple.

```
char cGrade = 9-(score/10)+65;
if( cGrade > 68 )
{
    cGrade = 70; // for 'F'
}
else if( cGrade < 65 )
{
    cGrade = 65; // for 'A'
}
```