# How do I solve the error: switch quantity not an integer and error: case label does not reduce to a an integral constant"

Tags: c

I am using C language to make program that selects employees in a project team based on their average points achieved in various criteria like MVP, so the error am getting is in the `switch` statement that says `error: switch quantity not an integer`, and the second error is `error: case label does not reduce to a an integral constant`

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    printf("Google Team Selection\n\n");
    double a, b, c, sum, average;
    printf("Enter your Minimum Viable Product(MVP) points here:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    printf("Enter your Apprenticer Programmer points here:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    printf("Enter your consistency points here:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &c);
    printf("Enter your qocient points");
    sum = a + b + c;
    average = sum / 3.0;
    printf(" the sum is %lf and the average is %lf", sum, average);
    switch (average) {
      case ">55":
        printf("Congratulations you have been selected\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

So, I want my program to select employees whose average is above `55`.

Comment: Sorry, but how does this relate with StrongLoop? As per-the tag description: “ StrongLoop is an API tier for connecting enterprise data to devices and browsers.
 It includes LoopBackJS, StrongOps, and StrongNode.”

Comment: Answered by any decent book/tutorial, or duplicate of various questions that ask about ranges/greater/lesser in switch statements, e.g. [Larger than and less than in C switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972297/larger-than-and-less-than-in-c-switch-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Switch requires an integer or a character or an expression that has as output either an int or a char. And the case need a constant-expression too. You can check the [switch microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/switch-statement-c?view=msvc-160).

In this case you should just use if-else.

So:

```
if (average > 55) {
   printf("Congratulations you have been selected\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `switch` in C for your purpose: the switch expression (`average`) and the `case` expressions must be integers.

You should use a simple `if` statement:

```
    if (average > 55) {
        printf("Congratulations you have been selected\n");
    }
```