# trying to create a switch with logical operators

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Hours;
    cout << "please enter number of hours worked";
    cin >> Hours;
    switch (Hours)
    {
    case 1: Hours == 40;
        cout << "worked full time this week";
        break;
    case 2:   Hours <= 30;
        cout << "You worked less than 40 this week available shifts on board";
        break;
    case 3: Hours > 30 && Hours < 40;
        cout << "You almost have 40 hrs check the board to see if shifts are available please do not go over 40 hrs";
        break;
    default: 
        cout << " invalid entry see you manager or try again";
    }



    {



    return 0;

}
```

I've done something wrong honestly do not really understand switch statements so just doing something pretty basic. I am getting a build error every time I try to run it. I want the user to input how many hrs worked and based on that display the message. I think an if/else statement would honestly be better but wanted to use a switch statement to get some practice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Larger than and less than in C switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972297/larger-than-and-less-than-in-c-switch-statement)

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way you use `switch`

`switch` will take the value and compare it with all `case`. You can't do larger and less using `switch`.

You should use `if-else` instead:

```cpp
if(Hours == 40)
{
    std::cout << "worked full time this week";
}
else if(Hours <= 30)
{
    std::cout << "You worked less than 40 this week available shifts on board";
}
else if(Hours > 30 && Hours < 40)
{
    std::cout << "You almost have 40 hrs check the board to see if shifts are available please do not go over 40 hrs";
}
else
{
    std::cout << " invalid entry see you manager or try again";
}
```